# How does caret handle the sampsize parameter when cross-validating a random forest?

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, cross-validation

I am working on a highly imbalanced two-class classification problem where a large proportion of the records corresponds to the majority class. One of the techniques I am looking into is a Random Forest where the bootstrap sample for each separate tree is created by downsampling the majority class. The randomForest package provides an easy implementation for this, for example:

```
library(caret)
# Generate random train/test data
train <- twoClassSim(500, intercept = -13)
test <- twoClassSim(500, intercept = -13)

library(randomForest)
# Calculate the size of the minority class
nmin <- min(table(train$Class))
# Fit randomForest
fit <- randomForest(Class ~ ., data = train, ntree = 50, replace=T,
                    strata = train$Class, sampsize = c(nmin,nmin))
```

In the code above, the parameters *strata* and *sampsize* are used to tell randomForest to downsample each bootstrap sample. Note that the parameter *sampsize* cannot be larger than the amount of records in the minority class. The following snippet of code for example, will return an error:

```
fit <- randomForest(Class ~ ., data = train, ntree = 5000, replace=T,
                    strata = train$Class, sampsize = c(nmin+1,nmin+1))

Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  sampsize can not be larger than class frequency
```

The first results are promising and I want to experiment with different values of *mtry* to hopefully squeeze out a few extra percent. To do so I use caret:

```
# Set trainControl for 10-fold cross-validation
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", classProbs = TRUE, 
summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

# Evaluate three values of mtry with caret
fit2 <- train(Class ~ ., data = train, method = "rf", ntree = 50, 
      metric = "ROC", trControl = ctrl,
      tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry = c(2,5,10)),
  strata = train$Class, sampsize = c(nmin,nmin))
```

And now my question:
Since 10-fold CV is applied, caret sends about 90% of the training data to randomForest for each fold. As a result, the number of samples in the minority class for these subsets will be smaller than nmin. However, the error 'sampsize can not be larger than class frequency' is not thrown by the code snippet above. Does this mean that caret adjusts the *sampsize* parameter. And if so, how is it adjusted?

Long story, hope it is clear!
Thanks in advance,
Arno

Comment: Have you looked at `library("DMwR");?SMOTE` and `library("ROSE");?ROSE`, they are special implementations do deal with heavily imbalanced classification problems

Comment: I thought it was a good question and surprised it didn't get a detailed answer. While this doesn't explain exactly how it works, this article shows that under (or over) sampling does work within caret, but not sure that you can set specific `sampsize`, [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/dealing-with-unbalanced-data-in-machine-learning/)

Comment: Thanks for the article, Caret does indeed provide nice functionality for under-sampling. The drawback of using this functionality is that the sampling is done before the model is trained: a subset of data is sent to the randomForest call. When using the strata/sampsize approach, ALL the data can be sent to randomForest. This basically allows you to apply downsampling without loss of data. I guess that the sampsize parameter is ignored in Caret?

Comment: Just did a quick check by adding 'keep.inbag = T' in the code above. fit2$finalModel$inbag shows that the downsampling is applied correctly: each tree in the forest is trained on 2*nmin rows of data. Thus, Caret does allow you to set a specific value for sampsize. Still, I would expect an error when applying Cross-Validation.